# can exif tag exisits with steganogrpahy

Tags: exif, steganography

I am trying to use steganography and exif to-gather can it be done ?? as in hide data in a file without destroying the exif image.

thanks
andy

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only alter the pixel data and not any header-related data, then sure, why not?